# Maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I 'm trying to select 170k records from a oracle database, there are some how to avoid this error? or any way to improve this query ?

thanks.

```
 
    select sr.RELATED_PON, srsi.VALID_VALUE 
    from SERV_REQ sr
    inner join SERV_REQ_SI_VALUE srsi
    on sr.DOCUMENT_NUMBER = srsi.DOCUMENT_NUMBER
    inner join SERV_ITEM si
    on si.SERV_ITEM_ID = srsi.SERV_ITEM_ID
    and si.STATUS = '6'
    where srsi.VALUE_LABEL = 'unitAddress'
    and srsi.VALID_VALUE in ('1682511819',
    '1682575135',
    '1682580326'
    ... more than 150k here!
    )
```

Comment: that's insane. Can't you put those 150k values on a table and use a join or an `in (SELECT ....`?

Comment: You could write it as `and ( srsi.VALID_VALUE in ('1682511819',
    '1682575135',
    '1682580326'
    ... less than 150k here!
    ) OR srsi.VALID_VALUE in ( '222222222','333333333'.... next 100K here) OR srsi.VALID_VALUE in ('4444444444','5555555555' ... )  etc etc )` but I agree with @Lamak - _you're doing it wrong_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lamak is correct: This really looks like a list that belongs in a table.

However, if this is not convenient for whatever reason, you must break the IN clause into chunks of no more than 1000 elements each.  Happily, this is pretty trivial: You insert `) OR ( scri.VALID_VALUE in` every 1000 items.

Unfortunately, you're soon going to bump into the max size of a query string. (For Oracle, I think that's 32K)... but seriously consider a temp table or something.

Comment: Thank you very much Kenneth Sizer, with this improvement I could do. :)